# Setting fixed variable value in class to be used when creating object

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I'm still relatively new to coding/Java so working through some practical tasks to learn. Having an issue i have 3 Classes all set up to reflect Main, Super etc

In my main method i'm creating objects that references another class- the issue i am having is setting the value for one attribute in particular and having it fixed?.

**Classes**- Main(entry point), Animal, Dog (Subclass of Animal), Jackrussel (Subclass of Dog)

In Main class- Creating new Jackrussel object (pulls right fields from constructors)

Issue- Within the Jackrussel class- i have set the Dog type to Jackrussel within the constructor-
this.dogtype = "Jack Russel"'

Yet when i create the object in main it doesnt automatically set dogtype to jackrussell. Am i defining this in the wrong area? As any Jackrussel object must have the dogtype always as Jackrussell? I would want this value to automatically pull through as it's set within that classes constructor?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

From what you explained, it sounds like you might have called `super(...)` (constructor of the superclass) in the constructor of `Jackrussel` after `this.dogtype = "Jack Russell"`. Doing so will override the statement if there is also an assignment of `dogtype` in the constructor of `Dog`.

It will be clearer if you include some code snippets, as there can be many reasons for your bug.

Answer (score 0):

With camel-case spelling conventions:

```
public class Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public final String dogType;

    public Dog(String dogType) {
        this.dogType = dogType; // Field becomes parameter.
    }
}

public class JackRussel extends Dog {
    public JackRussel() {
        super("Jack Russel");
    }
}

Animal animal = new JackRussel();
Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
System.out.println(dog.dogType);
```